# Stop `useMutation` from re-rendering component and ignore result

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

### **I have a mutation called like this (this isn't the actual mutation call, but a minimal example):**

```
const App = () => {
  const [myMutation] = useMutation(gql`
    mutation Test($updateUserId: ID!, $updateUserInput: UpdateUserInput!) {
      updateUser(id: $updateUserId, input: $updateUserInput) {
        id
        firstname
        age
      }
    }
  `);

  // Runs every time this component is rendered
  console.log("rendered");

  // Called when the button is clicked
  const update = () => {
    myMutation({
      variables: {
        updateUserId: 1,
        updateUserInput: {
          age: Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 5) // Set a random age from 5 - 15
        }
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Update Test</h1>
      <button onClick={update}>Update!</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Whenever `onClick` is called, the whole component is re-rendered. This is not what I want, as I don't care about the result of the mutation. Is there any way to stop `myMutation` from causing a re-render, and ignore the result completely?

Comment: Usually, useMutation does not trigger re-render until you are subscribed to some values inside the cache.

Comment: @RyanLe What do you mean by this? Can you give an example?

Comment: I would need to see the bigger picture of your app. Do you have a link to your repo?

Comment: @RyanLe Sorry, I don't have a link to my repo. Is it possible to demonstrate it using CodeSandbox, or something like that? I also can try to make a basic skeleton of how my program works if that's what you need.

Comment: Sure, that's will do. You could try to reproduce it by codesanbox. I will jump right in.

Comment: @RyanLe I've made a really barebones example: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-chandrasekhar-xtpky?file=/src/App.js - whenever the update button is clicked, the console shows that the component is re-rendered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236793/discussion-between-megargayu-and-ryan-le).

Comment: I put an answer below, see if you need any additional clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **`useMutation` is a hook and it has `state` in it which cause a re-render**

**See the `useMultation` type bellow:**

```
export interface MutationResult<TData = any> {
    data?: TData | null;
    error?: ApolloError;
    loading: boolean;
    called: boolean;
    client: ApolloClient<object>;
}
```

**The `loading` state is the one causing re-render, so in which component you delcare `useMutation` it will re-render due to that `state`**

---

**One possible fix is to separate the component with `useMutation` to another one**

Something like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />  // <-- this coponent won't re-render
      <UpdateUserButton />  // <-- useMutation is in here!
    </>
  );
}
```

Checkout the live example:

[image: Edit sweet-cohen-4w6ef]

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there a way that I can stop `Header` from updating, though? I've heard about `React.memo`, etc. but I don't know how those work. In any case thanks for your answer!

Comment: loading is a `state` so I don't think that's possible. Separate components for specific actions is also a best practice to "separate of concerns".

Comment: You could vote or mark an answer as accept if you find it useful and highlight it for others who need.

Comment: Sorry, I know I can do that, I had to go after my comment. Thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: Thank you!, This means a lot

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you don't need the `data` returned by the mutation, you can also pass the `ignoreResults` option. Data will not be returned from the mutation hook but `loading` would called neither which prevents a re-render.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#ignoreresults

```
const [someMutation] = useSomeMutation({
 ignoreResults: true,
});
```

Comment: This should be the most upvoted answer

Answer (score 1):

Following should work (not tested)

- Since you don't want re-render, you don't need to use useMutation hook which has state.
- Instead you can directly import you apollo-client and use mutate on it without using useMutation hook.
- You can choose to use the result in .then function or get rid of it.

```
import { apolloClient } from '../yourApolloClientFile';


const App = () => {

  const myMutation = (vars) => apolloClient.mutate({
    mutation: gql`
        mutation Test($updateUserId: ID!, $updateUserInput: UpdateUserInput!) {
          updateUser(id: $updateUserId, input: $updateUserInput) {
            id
            firstname
            age
          }
        }
      `,
    variables: vars
  })
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))


  // Runs every time this component is rendered
  console.log("rendered");

  // Called when the button is clicked
  const update = () => {
    myMutation({
      updateUserId: 1,
      updateUserInput: {
        age: Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 5) // Set a random age from 5 - 15
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Update Test</h1>
      <button onClick={update}>Update!</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: ++ to the tip to do the mutation directly with apollo client (I used the `useApolloClient` hook)

This means you can still access the data you need, while skipping the state update that rerenders your component.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because the mutation is returning a normalised object which this component or a higher component depends on via a hook like useQuery.

If you don't care about the result of the mutation make sure it doesn't return the normalised object.

Something like

```
mutation SomeMutation ($input: SomeMutationInput!){
  someMutation (input: $input){
    ok
  }
}
```

Comment: So... how do I fix it? If this is the case, how can I stop depending on it?

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#supported-fetch-policies 
It seems like fetchPolicy="standby" should work, but it doesn't for me